# get column data and insert into a row with id given in another column - sql nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I have made a certain form with a table layout
the table is kind of like this below:

UAN    NAME     DESIGNATION   No. of Days Present

87982   JOHN  SALESMAN     25

now, the columns uan name and designation are already given (taken from the database) and the user only needs to put in the attendance.
the number of days will then be inserted into the database
in the row where UAN = 87892

The problem is that I am unable to figure out how to get the value of UAN from the page and use it to enter the number of days in the database.

could you give some idea how to accomplish this using nodejs??
I am using the ejs templating system and mysql database.

that's not the only problem. 
I also want to enter the number of days present for all the different employees
where the number of days gets added to the row with their UAN number.
how am I supposed to do that?

any ideas??

here's the code for the attendance page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><title>attendance for employees</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
 <th>Serial No.</th>              
<th>UAN</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Attendance</th>
</tr>
<form action="/attendance-data" method="post">
     <% var i=0 %>
<% rows.forEach(function(item){ %>
       <% i=i+1 %>
     <tr>
          <td><%= i+"." %></td>
        <td id="uan<%= i %>"> <%= item.uan  %> </td>
        <td><%= item.name %></td>
        <td><%= item.designation %></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="attendance <%= i %>" ></td>
     </tr>
    <% });   %>
</form>


    </table>
</div>
<div>

<input type="button" value="submit" />


</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: assign an id and name to the th tag with the UAN value and reference it from the endpoint

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. could you give an example??

Comment: yes,  give me a bit

Comment: sure please go ahead .

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: ah, yes. 
It did help.
sorry,for not accepting this as the answer earlier.
I went on to applying your answer and then changed a few things here and there and got too invovled in it.
 I am going to accept this as the answer right now.

Comment: No problem,  wanted to make sure you had it.  It would be kinda cool if you updated your question with what you actually  used as well in case someone down the road has the same issue.  Good luck

Comment: ok, I'll do that in a bit. would love it if you could help with another question of mine. I have linked to it below your answer

Comment: I will take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the data from the page and insert it into your database:
`WHERE uan = '[data_from_html]'`, you will need to reference it by name. This can be accomplished when the user enters into the form how many days of attendance. The biggest issue you will have is that forms are tough to get working in correspondence to a table. You can put an entire table inside of a form but not the other way around necessarily.

Inside of your last td tag it would be best to place the entire form there with only one field visible and the rest hidden(you can still display as you were, just leave the other fields out of the form:

```
          <td>
            <form action='/attendance-data' method='post'>
                <input type='hidden' id='uan<%= i %>' name='attendance' value ='<%= i %>'/>
                <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value ='<%= i %>'/>
                <input type='hidden' name='designation' value ='<%= item.designation %>'/>
                <input type='text' name='attendance' value ='<%= i %>'/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </td>
```

Then inside of your routes in express:

```
app.post('/attendance-data', function(req, res) {
    var uan = req.body.uan
    var item_name = req.body.item_name
    var designation = req.body.designation
    var attendance = req.body.attendance

    // Make sure they all contain some sort of value

    var connString = new ConnectionString(
        config.mysql.host,
        config.mysql.port,
        config.mysql.username,
        config.mysql.password,
        config.mysql.default_db
    )

    var MySqlConn = new MySqlConnection(connString)

    // Proceed to do an update/insert into your db
    MySqlConn.Connection.query("insert into [your_table] " +
    "values(uan, item_name, designation, attendance) where uan='" + uan + "'",
    function (err) 
    { 
        if (err) 
        { 
            console.log(err.stack)
            throw err
        }
        // Otherwise success
        res.status(200).send('blah')

    })
}
```

Comment: by the way, could you help with another question of mine?
here's the link to it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919887/payroll-system-attendance-database-table-for-each-month